# Visualizar cambios de un colaborador GitHub

Tags: github

Tengo un repositorio y añadí a un colaborador, después mi colaborador agregó un script de R al repositorio pero no logró visualizar el script que subió,
Alguien sabe cual es el problema? O que es lo que tengo que hacer para poder ver los cambios que hizo?

Comment: Cómo lo quieres visualizar? En la página? En la aplicación de escritorio(Manerra más sencilla)? En consola?

Comment: Es que no logró ver el script que mi colaborador añadió entonces quiero saber cómo puedo ver o descargar ese script, no se si tenga que habilitar un permiso o algo para poder verlo, que como veo es en el escritorio, por eso solicito la ayuda, soy nuevo utilizando GitHub y apenas estoy viendo cómo funciona

Comment: En ese caso para `github desktop` solo seleccionas el repositorio y vas a la pestaña del historial, ahi puedes ver cada commit con los cambios realizados al repositorio.

Answer (score 0):

Es probable que tu colaborador haya subido el cambio en un branch diferente o incluso pudo haber hecho un fork al proyecto.

Te recomiendo ir a la sección de **"Insights"** y después seleccionar **"Network"** a tu izquierda, ahí podrás visualizar la actividad en el repositorio.

Si la actividad de tu colaborador esta en otro branch, selecciona el indicado en la primera pagina del repositorio, el branch default suele ser *Main*.